# Pivoting table throws error: "only simple column names allowed here"

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a dataset, example:

`Master` table:

```
x------x----------x-----------------x-----------x--------x
| Chasisnumber   |    Messagename |   PaintML | Result
x------x--------------------x-------x-----------x--------x
| A123           |   Message1       |   10    |   OK
| A123           |   Message2       |   70    |   NOK 
  B123           |   Message1       |   10    |   OK
  B123           |   Message2       |   50    |   OK
x------x--------------------x-------x-----------x--------x
```

I want to get:

```
Chasisnumber, PaintML-Message1 ,Result-Message1,PaintML-Message2,Result-Message2

| A123           | 10    |   OK  | 70    |   NOK
  B123           | 10    |   OK  | 50    |   OK
```

This can be done with pivot. Can someone help me out?

Example:

```
select *
from 
    (Select chasis, message, paint, result 
     from paint_b) src
pivot
(
  src.Paint, src.result for src.MessageName in 
  ('Message1',
  'Message2')
) piv;
```

Comment: What about dates in your master table

Comment: There is no date.

Comment: Please share expected output in text format, column names and  one row of data

Comment: I would personally use a Cross Tab instead, they are far for versatile than the `PIVOT` operator

Comment: Show me code please

Comment: you actually want message name in result and paintML columns right ?

Comment: I need to get 1 record for every chasisnumber; PaintML-M1, Result-M1, PaintML-M2, Result-M2,

Comment: Added example to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i mentioned, a cross tab seems like a better idea:

```
--Sample Data
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT V.Chasisnumber,
           V.Messagename,
           V.PaintML,
           V.Result
    FROM (VALUES('A123','Message1',10,'OK'),
                ('A123','Message2',70,'NOK'), 
                ('B123','Message1',10,'OK'),
                ('B123','Message2',50,'OK')) V(Chasisnumber,Messagename,PaintML,Result))
--Solution
SELECT V.Chasisnumber,
       MAX(CASE V.Messagename WHEN 'Message1' THEN V.PaintML END) AS PaintML1,
       MAX(CASE V.Messagename WHEN 'Message2' THEN V.PaintML END) AS PaintML2,
       MAX(CASE V.Messagename WHEN 'Message1' THEN V.Result END) AS Result1,
       MAX(CASE V.Messagename WHEN 'Message2' THEN V.Result END) AS Result2
FROM VTE V
GROUP BY V.Chasisnumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want:

```
create table #tmp (Chasisnumber VARCHAR(10),Messagename VARCHAR(25), PaintML INT,Result VARCHAR(10))
insert into #tmp values
('A123','Message1',10,'OK'),
('A123','Message2',70,'NOK'), 
('B123','Message1',10,'OK'),
('B123','Message2',50,'OK')

select * from (
select Chasisnumber, unpiv.val, unpiv.col+'-'+unpiv.Messagename as col
from (select Chasisnumber,Messagename,cast(PaintML as varchar(10)) PaintML,Result from #tmp) tmp
unpivot (val for col in (PaintML,Result)) unpiv )a
pivot (max(val) for col in ([PaintML-Message1],[Result-Message1],[PaintML-Message2],[Result-Message2])) piv
```

Comment: Very Strong example.